# Get base address of share library using GDB

Tags: linux, gdb, shared-libraries, gdbserver

How can I get the base address of share library using GDB ?

I couldn't find any easy way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `info sharedlibrary`:

```
$ gdb -ex 'b main' -ex r --args bash --help
(gdb) pipe info sharedlibrary | grep libtinfo
0x00007ffff7f8e6a0  0x00007ffff7f9c17c  Yes (*)     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6
```

Note that load address will be different on each invocation due to ASLR.